# If statement evaluation and best practice

Tags: php, if-statement

In this code the variable `$controller` has been initialized and used (code is from Prestashop v1.6)

```
$current_index = 'index.php'.(($controller = Tools::getValue('controller')) ? '?controller='.$controller : '');
```

What counts as not true in this if block?  How is this block evaluated?

Is this considered best practice?

Comment: If $controller gets assigned a falsy value then the 2nd condition will execute.

Comment: is null also a *falsy* ?

Comment: Yes it is.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php and look under the loose comparisons with == table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$current_index` will equal the string `index.php` if `Tools::getValue('controller')` evaluates to false.

If you convert the block into a non-ternary operation you can see the assignment clearer:

```
$controller = Tools::getValue('controller');
if ($controller) {
    $parameter = '?controller=' . $controller;
} else {
    $parameter = '';
}
$current_index = 'index.php' . $parameter;
```

Ternary operations are best practice, but in the example code you've provided it's not entirely clear due to both the URL parameter assignment and the ternary operation happening on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it as,

```
  $controller = Tools::getValue('controller');
  $current_index = 'index.php'.(($controller) ? '?controller='.$controller : '');
```